# Accessing Vuex Store Before Page Load NuxtJS

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vue2-google-maps

**Context:**  I am trying to get Google Maps place data via the place_id on the beforeEnter() route guard. Essentially, I want the data to load when someone enters the url exactly [www.example.com/place/{place_id}](http://www.example.com/place/%7Bplace_id%7D). Currently, everything works directly when I use my autocomplete input and then enter the route but it does not work when I directly access the url from a fresh tab. I've been able to solve this using the `beforeEnter()` route guard in traditional Vue, but cannot solve for this using Nuxt.  Please help!

**Question:** How can I access the Vuex Store before a page loads in Nuxt?

**Error:** Any solution I try (see below) I either end up with a blank page or the page will not load (I think it is stuck in a loop and cannot resolve the Promise).

**Attempted Solutions:**

1. Using Middleware like below:

```js
  middleware({ store, params }) {
    return store.dispatch('myModule/fetchLocation', params.id)
  }
```

2. Using asyncData like below:

```js
data(){
  return{
    filteredLocation: {}
  }
}

// snip

async asyncData({ store, params }) {
  const { data } = await store.dispatch('myModule/fetchLocation', params.id)
  return filteredLocation = data
}
```

3. I tried looking into fetch, but apparently you no longer have access to `context`

**Example Code:**

In one of my store modules:

```js
/* global google */

import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from '~/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/src/main'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: process.env.VUE_APP_GMAP_KEY,
    libraries: 'geometry,drawing,places'
  }
})

export const state = () => ({
  selectedLocation: {}
})

export const actions = {
  fetchLocation({ commit }, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      Vue.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() => {
        const request = {
          placeId: params,
          fields: [
            'name',
            'rating',
            'formatted_phone_number',
            'geometry',
            'place_id',
            'website',
            'review',
            'user_ratings_total',
            'photo',
            'vicinity',
            'price_level'
          ]
        }
        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
          document.createElement('div')
        )
        service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            commit('SET_PLACE', place)
            resolve()
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_PLACE: (state, selection) => {
    state.selectedInstructor = selection
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I already have it in a plugin named `google-maps.js` and in my `nuxt.config.js` file I have:

```js
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/google-maps.js' }
  ]
//
//
  build: {
    transpile: [/^vue2-google-maps.js($|\/)/],
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Middleware is how we can access Vuex before page loads. try putting the configuration part in a custom Nuxt plugin.
Create a file in Plugins folder (you can name it global.js).
Put this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from '~/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/src/main'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
 load: {
  key: process.env.VUE_APP_GMAP_KEY,
libraries: 'geometry,drawing,places'
}
})
```

in global.js.
Then add the plugin in nuxt.config.js like this.

```
 plugins: [
  '~/plugins/global.js' 
 ]
```

Also, make sure you're using underscore before 'page_id' name in your folder structure.

Comment: Sorry this was not mentioned in the initial post (i've since edited).  I already have it in a plugin named `google-maps.js` and in my `nuxt.config.js` file I have:

```javascript
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/google-maps.js' }
  ]
//
//
  build: {
    transpile: [/^vue2-google-maps.js($|\/)/],
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
```